# Express-Node JS handlebar templating in res.render: How to iterate?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have this problem. Would you mind helping me?

**PROBLEM:** There are hundreds of rows returned by the database.
Therefore, the codes below should have hundreds of entries in the "tile".
Is there any way to automate such a process?
A way to create another entry, wherein the row that is to be used is the next row?

A way to use loops such as while, if else statements or for loops?

**I have this code in app.js**:

```
app.get('/gallery', function (req, res,next) {

connection.query("select firstname,entryid,pictureid, surname, title, fileurl from entries LIMIT 100", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err)
    throw err;

    var count = rows.length;
    var i = 0;

res.render('gallery', {
                tile : 
                    [
                        {
                            firstname : [rows[i].firstname],
                            title : rows[i].title,
                            artist : rows[i].firstname + ' ' + rows[i].surname,
                            fileurl : rows[i].fileurl,
                            surname : rows[i].surname,
                            entryid :rows[i].entryid,
                            view_count : genRandNum(),
                            pictureid : rows[i].pictureid,
                        },
                        {
                            firstname : [rows[2].firstname],
                            title : rows[2].title,
                            artist : rows[2].firstname + ' ' + rows[i].surname,
                            fileurl : rows[2].fileurl,
                            surname : rows[2].surname,
                            entryid :rows[2].entryid,
                            view_count : genRandNum(),
                            pictureid : rows[2].pictureid,
                        },
                        {
                            firstname : [rows[3].firstname],
                            title : rows[3].title,
                            artist : rows[3].firstname + ' ' + rows[i].surname,
                            fileurl : rows[3].fileurl,
                            surname : rows[3].surname,
                            entryid :rows[3].entryid,
                            view_count : genRandNum(),
                            pictureid : rows[3].pictureid,
                        },
                        {
                          // .......the next row[i] should be used................
                        }
                    ]
                });
        });
```

**My HTML code is this:**
(It doesn't really help, but at least you could grasp what I want to happen.
This page is a gallery page, by the way. That is why I have plenty of `"tile"`)

```
{{#tile}}
        <div class="medium-4 large-4 columnGallery" >
            <div class="gallery shadow">
                <a href="/entry-details-page/{{entryid}}/{{pictureid}}" class="artist-avatar"><img src="{{fileurl}}"></a>
                <div class="artist-name">
                    <a href="/public/{{firstname}}-{{surname}}" class="username">{{artist}}</a>
                    <a href="/public" class="artist-username">{{username}}</a>
                </div>
                <span class="view-count">{{view_count}} views</span>
                <a href="/entry-details-page/{{entryid}}/{{pictureid}}" class="photo-tile-title">{{title}}</a>
                <div class="action">
                    <div data-date="2013-12-06T22:13:37.122Z" class="story-date moment fromNow">Entry: 2012</div>
                    <div class="story-tile-thumbnail"><a href="/entry-details-page/{{entryid}}/{{pictureid}}"><img src="{{fileurl}}"></a></div>
                </div>

            </div>  
        </div>
{{/tile}}
```

So this is now the new **code :**

```
rows.forEach(function(rows) {
        tile.push({
            firstname  : rows.firstname,
            title      : rows.title,
            artist     : rows.firstname + ' ' + rows.surname,
            fileurl    : rows.fileurl,
            surname    : rows.surname,
            entryid    : rows.entryid,
            view_count : genRandNum(),
            pictureid  : rows.pictureid,
        });

        console.log(rows);
    });

    res.render('gallery', {
            tile : [rows]
        });

    console.log(tile);
     });
```

and console.log(tile) outputs the right code which is in this FORMAT :

```
[
                    {   
                        firstname : [rows[i].firstname],
                        title : rows[i].title,
                        artist : rows[i].firstname + ' ' + rows[i].surname,
                        fileurl : rows[i].fileurl,
                        surname : rows[i].surname,
                        entryid :rows[i].entryid,
                        view_count : genRandNum(),
                        pictureid : rows[i].pictureid,
                    },
                    {   
                        firstname : [rows[i].firstname],
                        title : rows[i].title,
                        artist : rows[i].firstname + ' ' + rows[i].surname,
                        fileurl : rows[i].fileurl,
                        surname : rows[i].surname,
                        entryid :rows[i].entryid,
                        view_count : genRandNum(),
                        pictureid : rows[i].pictureid,
                    },
                ]
```

BUT HTML PAGE STILL SHOWS BLANK :(

```
{{#each tile}}
        <div class="medium-4 large-4 columnGallery" >
            <div class="gallery shadow">
                <a href="/entry-details-page/{{entryid}}/{{pictureid}}" class="artist-avatar"><img src="{{fileurl}}"></a>
                <div class="artist-name">
                    <a href="/public/{{firstname}}-{{surname}}" class="username">{{artist}}</a>
                    <a href="/public" class="artist-username">{{username}}</a>
                </div>
                <span class="view-count">{{view_count}} views</span>
                <a href="/entry-details-page/{{entryid}}/{{pictureid}}" class="photo-tile-title">{{title}}</a>
                <div class="action">
                    <div data-date="2013-12-06T22:13:37.122Z" class="story-date moment fromNow">Entry: 2012</div>
                    <div class="story-tile-thumbnail"><a href="/entry-details-page/{{entryid}}/{{pictureid}}"><img src="{{fileurl}}"></a></div>
                </div>

            </div>  
        </div>
        {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

create the `tile` array of objects in a loop, then pass it to `render()`

```
app.get('/gallery', function (req, res, next) {
    connection.query("select firstname,entryid,pictureid, surname, title, fileurl from entries LIMIT 100", function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var tile = [];

        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            tile.push({
                firstname  : [row.firstname],
                title      : row.title,
                artist     : row.firstname + ' ' + row.surname,
                fileurl    : row.fileurl,
                surname    : row.surname,
                entryid    : row.entryid,
                view_count : genRandNum(),
                pictureid  : row.pictureid
            });
        });
        res.render('gallery', {tile});
    });
});
```

You can do the same in the HTML, I usually use Jade or EJS, but I'm sure Handlebars has a way to iterate as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! :) But no data seems to appear now. I've did what you stated. For example : Is row.title alright? Shouldn't we have row[index].title??

Comment: Nope, it's `row.title` where `row` is the current item in the loop. @user3094180

Comment: THANKS! The problem now, is that when i do console.log(row) to see what is outputted, yes there are iterations, but there is no comma between the blocks : {
                firstname  : [row.firstname],
                title      : row.title,
                artist     : row.firstname + ' ' + row.
                ...
            }
{
                firstname  : [row.firstname],
                title      : row.title,
                artist     : row.firstname + ' ' + row.
                ...
            }

Comment: JUST this last issue :( I really need to finish this project. Everything is already fine, except that in between each iteration, there is no COMMA, which is a NEED :(

Comment: @user3094180 - comma where exactly ?

Comment: OH. That was a stupid question, when i output the tile now, there is already an iterated blocks, no mistakes. But why aren't the data used and shown in the html? Nothing appears in the html. :(

Comment: I don't really know much about Handlebars, and it's hard to tell what is being sent to the template without have anything to test, but the data should be exactly the same as the one you had, there is no difference in the resulting array wether one iterates or adds each object manually.